# Show routed url in address bar, not main url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

Here i create a url route in `Global.asax` file :

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "My Home Page", "~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Now i want to show `https://www.example.com/My Home Page` to the client when he/she types `https://www.example.com` in the address bar of browser & hit enter.
For every `.aspx` web page i want do similiar.
What is the simplest way to show routed url in address bar, not main url?
Please show me both **c#** & **web.config** ways.

---

**Edit :** 
I am in asp.net web form, Not core or MVC

Comment: What you need is a redirect not route!

Comment: Additionally you can use Url routing module.